# How to show more than 100 items in dropdown options using projections list

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a model "address", and one field is country, in the create/edit form I use dropdown to let user select from country list, country list is store in another model called "listCountry", there are 249 countries in total, but in the dropdown options, only first 100 countries shown.
[image]
My questions and concern are:

- In the options setting, I use @datasources.listCountry.items..Country, and I know there is [a default pagesize of 100](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#page_size), but I tried to change that property pageSize as suggested by google's doc, I added to Event Load of that dropdown `app.datasources.listCountry.query.pageSize = 300;`, but it doesn't work, any suggestion?
- I tried Search Box instead of dropdown as workaround, it works, but it requires to set a relation between Address model and listCountry model, which is not required when I use Dropdown. I'm wondering which is the best practice to store an option list, like in this case when we need give an list options such as country for an address form, is that relation setting necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you to set the default page size to 0 un the datasource settings of your model.

Comment: thanks @Morfinismo for the guidance.